# PHP. Процедура смены email

Tags: php, email, token

Есть таблица юзеров, которая содержит в себе разные записи. Среди них есть, думаю важные в нашем случае, такие записи: **id, email, token** - некий случайный уникальный стринг, который генерируется если нам нужно.
Достаточно ли этих записей для процедуры смены юзером email? Как вообще правильно это делать?

Есть такая идея: Юзер вводит в некую форму новый эмейл, сервер проверяет нет ли такого эмейла уже в БД. Если нет, отправляем на этот эмейл тело письма с ссылкой на php скрипт сервера, которая содержит GET параметр - token и припустим md5(id). Этот же token генерируется и записывается в БД к данному юзеру перед отправкой письма. 
Если новый эмейл действителен при переходе по ссылке, срабатывает скрипт который ищет в бд данный токен, если он существует сравнивает md5(id) этой записи в БД с get параметром md5(id) ссылки. Если Они ровны - все окей, можно менять эмайл.
Если идея верна, где теперь взять этот самый новый email?? Делать новое поле в БД напрbмер tempEmail и записывать его туда перед отправкой письма? Или же передавать как еще один get параметр в ссылке, но тогда его можно подменить на совсем другой email.

Comment: можно гет параметром, просто захешировать с какой-нибудь солью

Comment: Столкнулся с проблемой. Нашел функцию которая хэширует строку с помощью base64 с солью и ключом. Вот что получилось `&email=lo8Q6aSI0vKeuntzzHCcCA%3D%3D` - `hello@gmail.com`. Стоило заменить 8 на 9 `&email=lo9Q6aSI0vKeuntzzHCcCA%3D%3D`  и вышло `he,lo3@gmail.com`. Да нужно проверять еще и емейл на валидность, но я не думаю что будет сложно так подставить чтобы вышло например `herlo3@gmail.com`. Как эту проблему решать? Делать более сложное хеширование чтобы вероятность подмены была еще меньше?